# Java: Is there a way to get the custom parameters from Freemarker Template

Tags: java, freemarker

I want to get all the custom parameters defined in my template in my java code.
Example

```
<pre><code><html><head><style>td {
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 12px;
}</style></head><body>
<table width="16%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
     <td colspan="5" align="center">${test1}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="5" align="center">${test2}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body></html></code></pre>
```

I want something to get test1 and test2 parameters in my java code. So I want something below

```
Template template = this.getTemplate(ftl);
// a, should have test1, test2 and in case template any other template then it should get parameters for that too
String[] a= template.getAttributes();
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, and in the general case it's not possible. Even if the AST API was public (but it isn't), there are several complications that make it hard to tell what data-model variables are used. In a more complex template, it's not obvious if `test1` comes from the data-model, or was set inside the template. Also there can be `#import`-s and `#include`-s that can refer to further data-model variables, but are linked dynamically.

The approach of FreeMarker is that the data-model is known first, and the templates are written for it.